# How to maintain the order of insertion in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I am just wondering if I can maintain the order of insertion of data in SQL Server?

I am working on my own project and it is kind of blog site having a number of posts. I will save my posts to my SQL Server but I want them in the order of insertion.

Question: I understand that If I use auto-incrementing integer in SQL Server as the primary key, I can maintain the order of insertion. But I want to use "Guid" for primary key, instead of identity. Then "Guid" does not seem to maintain the order of insertion.

Should I use both auto-incrementing integer for order of insertion and Guid for identity?

Or Is there any other way to maintain the order of insertion with Guid set to primary key?

Related question: the reason why I want to maintain the order of insertion is that in that way, I don't have to use `order by` clause which causes extra sorting process.

But should not I trust the order of data returned from database without any ordering clauses like `order by`?

Should I always use some ordering clauses for ordering my data? Then what if I have a massive amount of data to order? Then how can I handle the situation?

Sorry for too many questions in a post but I believe they are all related.

Comment: A table is an unordered set of rows. even if you used guid and auto inc number, you'll still need to use order by to get  data in  a specific order. there is no such thing as insertion ordered table in RDBMS.

Comment: @GurV oh so when i actually use auto-inc number, the data is displayed by the order of insertion in Sql management studio but when I actually query the table, It does not guarantee the order/ is this what you mean?? sorry I am so new to database

Comment: Exactly, without an order by clause, there is no guarantee that data will be ordered.

Answer (score 3):

You are misguided.

SQL tables represent unordered sets.  If you want a result set in a particular order, then you need to use an `ORDER BY` clause in the query.  The SQL optimizer might not use the `ORDER BY`, finding another way to return the results in order.

You can have an `identity` column that is not the primary key.  But actually, you can have both an `identity` column and a `guid` column, with the former as the primary key and the latter as a unique key.  Another solution is to have a `CreatedAt` datetime.  You can use this for ordering . . . or even as a clustered index if you really wanted to.

Comment: I actually had Guid for primary key and datetime column for saving the time of insertion and set default = GETDATE() but It does not order the data by its insertion date. Should I set anything else??

Comment: oh so you meant if i have datetime column then I can use datatime column with orderby??

Comment: @Michael . . . Yes, of course.  You can also have an index on it for performance.  You have to use `order by`, of course.

Answer (score 1):

When you specify `ORDER BY` in an `INSERT...SELECT` statement, SQL Server will assign `IDENTITY` values in the order specified.  However, that does not mean rows are necessarily inserted in that order.

If you need rows returned in a specific order, you must use `ORDER BY` to guarantee ordering. Indexes can be leverage provide order data efficiently depending on the query particulars.

Comment: Oh so if i have a massive amount of data to order by its insertion date or whatever, then I should probably think of having index plan. Is it right?

Comment: I was just curious that Google must have a massive amount of data to compare and order by its date, how can it deal with that in the middle of setting up my database. ha

Comment: Google does not use a relational database for it's search engine. To avoid a sort in execution plan, the index key should include the equality `WHERE` clause predicates followed by the date for ordering and/or filtering.