# SQL Server -While Inserting my temp table data into main table its getting change the order

Tags: sql-server

While Inserting my temp table data into main table its getting change the order .But if you select the same its showing in proper order .
Note : I have given identity column for temp table and while inserting into main table using the order by column with identity.

Could you please provide the some suggestion to me.
Please find the example as follows.

```
DECLARE @TempTable as Table(LevelID int identity(1,1)  primary key,Header_ID int,typeid int,type varchar(100),name varchar(max),labelvalue varchar(max),
CreatedOn_DT datetime,CreatedBy_ID int,UpdatedOn_DT DATETIME,UpdatedBy_ID int)

Insert Into @TempTable (Header_ID,typeid,type,labelvalue,name,CreatedDT,CreatedBID,UpdatedDT,UpdatedByID)
EXECUTE sp_Result_one @id1,@id2,@id3
Go
Insert Into @TempTable (Header_ID,typeid,type,labelvalue,name,CreatedDT,CreatedBID,UpdatedDT,UpdatedByID)
EXECUTE sp_Result_Two @id1,@id2,@id3
Go
Insert Into @TempTable (Header_ID,typeid,type,labelvalue,name,CreatedDT,CreatedBID,UpdatedDT,UpdatedByID)
EXECUTE sp_Result_Three @id1,@id2,@id3
Go
Insert Into @TempTable (Header_ID,typeid,type,labelvalue,name,CreatedDT,CreatedBID,UpdatedDT,UpdatedByID)
EXECUTE sp_Result_Four @id1,@id2,@id3

GO
Insert into ResultTable(Header_ID,typeid,type,labelvalue,name,CreatedDT,CreatedBID,UpdatedDT,UpdatedByID)
select Header_ID,typeid,type,labelvalue,name,CreatedDT,CreatedBID,UpdatedDT,UpdatedByID from @TempTable order by LevelID asc
```

I have one temptable and populating data into it running four stored procedures and finally inserting the data into maintable from temptable.But its inserting the data into irrelevent order.

Comment: The only time order is guaranteed when selecting from a table is when you use `ORDER BY`. Insert order is (mostly) irrelevant.

Comment: Hey Surendra, can you please show a short example of what you refer to, and what you consider being the problem. In general, the only time you are guaranteed order is when you use `ORDER BY`.

Comment: Hey Niels,i have updated by query with one example snippet

Comment: Agree with what Nick said. The ONLY time an `order by` matters is to ensure the order of an identity column on the TARGET table (in your case, that would be ResultTable). But those identity values will be different than the ones in your table variable. It's also worth noting that the example you provided won't run for a couple reasons. If these comments don't answer your question sufficiently, it might help to provide an example which can be executed fully to show the issue and expectation.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41917452/how-to-maintain-the-order-of-insertion-in-sql-server

Comment: Hi Guys,Thank you for your support .I got answer for this query,at last inserting the data into main table will give the CURRENT_TIMESTAMP for CreatedDT instead of each and every time inserting the CURRENT_TIMESTAMP  for CreatedDT   into temptable.